# Cannot go to bottom of twitter page using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape all tweets from twitter using Selenium. So, for this I want to go at bottom of the page.I tried a lot but it shows "Back to top " as shown in image.
How can I go at the bottom of the page/disappear "Back to top" using Selenium or How can I scrape all the tweets, if applying any other approach?

```
import pandas as pd
import selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/piyush/geckodriver")
url="https://twitter.com/narendramodi"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(6)

lastHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(6)
    newHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if newHeight == lastHeight:
         break
    lastHeight = newHeight

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"),"html.parser")
tweet=[p.text for p in soup.find_all("p",class_="tweet-text")]
```

[Here is image of inspect element of "Back-to-top"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/734hv.png)

[Here is the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKaqM.png)

Comment: You are probably better off using the twitter API to gather all tweets if possible.

Comment: @ArranDuff Glad to hear but it's limitation in twitter API of 3240 tweets only. But I need more than it.

Comment: You can read batches of tweets: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/guides/working-with-timelines

Comment: @JensDibbern Tried but didn't work.Only scrape 3237 tweets.

Answer (score 0):

Just briefly looking at twitter, it appears that the content is generated on scrolling, meaning you need to scrape and parse the data as you scroll rather than after.

I would suggest moving

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"),"html.parser")
tweet = [p.text for p in soup.find_all("p",class_="tweet-text")]
```

into your while loop after the scroll:

```
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    ###
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"),"html.parser")
    tweet = [p.text for p in soup.find_all("p",class_="tweet-text")]
    ###
    time.sleep(6)
    newHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if newHeight == lastHeight:
         break
    lastHeight = newHeight
```

If this doesn't work you are probably being fingerprinted and labeled as a bot by Twitter.